# New Email-To-Case forwarding rules due to winter update?

Tags: apex, trigger, service-cloud-console

I created an email-to-case routing address. It generated an email service address as seen below:

company@2pi5gutw5ily4pqew3jiu5s5tnopsjngn3pzxv64x6py.4x-3wk2ieaq.na150.case.salesforce.com

Do we need to set up automatic forwarding from within GMAIL from each of our team's individual email addresses to the email service address to make sure that email replies are logging back to Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

The routing address is used by inbound email-to-case processing

So, if you have a publicly-facing email address like `support@mycompany.com`; you need to set up a forwarding rule on Gmail to forward:

- Incoming emails to `support@mycompany.com` should forward to ..
- `company@2pi5gutw5ily4pqew3jiu5s5tnopsjngn3pzxv64x6py.4x-3wk2ieaq.na150.case.salesforce.com`

What you want to do is have the outgoing emails from your team members to have a `replyTo` set to `support@mycompany.com` (the emails can appear to the recipient as coming from the agent's name, e.g. `Angela Agent`). You can set this up in each agent's Email Settings.

Comment: It does not look like we can set a reply to email address inside of Salesforce.

We can only set a reply to Email-Message